# Can't connect C# Program to mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

For my program, I want to use mySQL as a storage for data that will be exported there and seen by the user. here I initailized a connection betweent the two:

```
        string MyConnection2 = "server=localhost;database=leaderboard;user=root;password=root";

        MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
        string Query = "insert into leaderboard.leaderboard(Name,Score,Lives, Time) values('" + nameText.Text + "','" + "','" + scoreLabel.Text + "','" + livesText.Text + "','" + timeText.Text + "');";
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        MyConn2.Open();
        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();

        if (MyConn2.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection established!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No connection established");
        }
```

However when I try to go that form with this during debugging, it comes up with this error:

```
  SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3306
```

What is causing this?

Comment: check your host file

Comment: Try uid instead of user

Comment: @Ravi this is shown there: # 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: what is the port number for your database ?

Comment: @Ravi it's 3306

Comment: this could be firewall or system setting issue. Could you try with `ip-address` instead of localhost ?

Comment: @SteveDarrenson If you open a command prompt and try to execute a `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306 ` what do you see?

Comment: @Christos it says that it's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @Ravi I changed the local host to my IP Address but now it comes up with this instead: MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: Not answering the question but there are a couple of things dangerously wrong in your code: 1. **Never** concatenate strings with user input to create your sql query. It's an open door to SQL Injection attacks. Use parameterized queries instead. 2. **Always** use the `using` statement when dealing with instances of classes that implements the `IDisposable` interface - in your case - `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader`.

Comment: there are lots of things wrong in your code but try to update your connectionstring by this "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=leaderboard;User Id=root;password=root"

Comment: and most important thing which i want to know is that do you changed the password ? of user root to root ? because i think by default its nothing and we had to left password=;  blank like this

Comment: he;d get a different error if the password was wrong i think...have you tried installing any other software outside of mysql itself to access the database?...for database manipulation?